# fgets not reading whole line, no new line character encountered

Tags: c, file-io, fgets

for some reason `fgets` reads lines from a file correctly until it reaches a certain line where it just gets part of the line. I checked the file with a Hex editor and there was no new line character in the middle of that line.

File:(pretty large. `fgets` stops at line 269)

```
/mmc_data/add_rootfs
...
/mmc_data/add_rootfs/data/local/sbin/mcast
```

Here's the line 269 in Hexadecimal representation:

```
2f 6d 6d 63 5f 64 61 74 61 2f 61 64 64 5f 72 6f 6f 74 66 73 2f 64 61 74 61 2f 6c 6f 63 61 6c 2f 73 62 69 6e 2f 6d 63 61 73 74 0a
```

I'm just combining `fgets` with `printf`:

```
char cBuffer[1024]="";
while(fgets(cBuffer,1024,fpLog){
printf("%s\n",cBuffer);
}
...
```

The program outputs everything correctly until it reaches line 269 and it only prints:

```
/mmc_data/a 
instead of 
/mmc_data/add_rootfs/data/local/sbin/mcast
```

The 1024 Bytes have clearly not been reached as well as a new line character. So why is fgets stopping at that postion?

Comment: Are we sure it's the input that's wrong and not the output? What does `strlen(cBuffer)` say?

Comment: The while loop exits after having printed such 11 characters?

Comment: Where you reading the file while some other process was writing to it? In that case reading may have stopped due to EOF.

Comment: @alk yes for some reason it exits after reading that line. Although there are more lines to read.

Comment: By "it exits" do you mean exits the loop or the program?

Comment: @KlasLindbäck I cannot think of anything that is accessing the file at the same time. My program is unithreaded.

Comment: I got it. I was writing to the file before and then attempted to use fgets. However I did not want to close the file and forgot to use fflush before reading from it. Actually @KlasLindbäck's comment made me think of `fflush` for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

Solved: I created the file before attempting to access its contents. I did not want to close the file. So the last portion stayed in the buffer and was not written to the file. I solved the issue by using `fflush(fpLog)`
between the writing and the reading